# How to find the last number in my case using SQL Server?

Tags: sql, sql-server, t-sql, substring

I have varchar with the combination of number and letters like below

**Sample record**

```
   ProductID
   ---------
   00000001
   00000001ws
   00000002re
   00000002
   00000015
   00001253gh
```

**Expecting Output**

```
 Output = 00001254
```

**Note**

Total digit must be 8. not more than that

Comment: How do you create a new number?

Comment: *"Total digit must be 8. not more than that"* Does that mean you could have values like `'1234567890ABC'` or `'01234XYZ'`? What have you tried so far to solve this yourself? Why didn't it work?

Comment: Which logic did yoy apply to get you output

Answer (score 1, accepted):

To get the last number, you can use:

```
select max(try_convert(int, left(productId, 8)))
from t;
```

To format one larger than this, you can use:

```
select format(max(try_convert(int, left(productId, 8))) + 1, '00000000')
from t;
```

Comment: thank you. something I learned the keyword `left,try_convert,format` how it works from your answer